# Dar formato a números con regex en flutter

Tags: regex, flutter

Como puedo formatear estos números con regex en flutter para que me arroje estos precios: 5.000, 10,000, 150.000, 150,000, 1.000.000, 25.000.000, 250.000.000. Intenté hacerlo así:

```
extension PriceValidator on String {
  bool isValidPrice () {
     return RegExp(r'^(\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*|(\d+))*(\.\d{3})$').hasMatch(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Me he perdido un poco, ¿quieres que se vea `150.000` o `150,000`? ¿O de qué debería depender si es con coma o con punto?

Comment: he puede ser así: 1.000.000 oh así 1,000.000

Comment: Tenés que decidir qué formato querés para el separador de miles: o comas, o puntos. ¿Qué pasaría si tu número tiene decimales?

Comment: Da igual como lo ponga en la regex, a la hora de escribir la cifra para publicar el producto, en el teclado no se me activa la coma solo el punto y cualquier cantidad de símbolos menos la coma... me dieron un ejemplo en una imagen para formatear la regex, pero no se como proceder..